# Angular 4 and Node.js combination

Tags: mongodb, angular, express

So as the title implies, I have a little problem. I'm developing app with Angular 4 and I would like to us it in combination with Node (mainly for API). So I tried to start both servers, and use it that way, but as i'm currently developing at local machine, so maybe there is better alternatives? Something like MEAN (MongoDb Express Angular Node) combination, but all of those are quite hard to use, there is lack of documentation, and those uses angular 2 instead of 4. I prefer MEAN stack, but I can't find one that are maintained and up to date.

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT**:

As some answers implied I will properly describe what I did to achieve what I need.

Here is what I have tried:

- Having two tools (Node and Angular) to communicate to each other via http protocol (actually this kind'a worked, but node wasn't stable, it broke with connection error to db and Angular would not get response from it until it crashes)
- Tried to use Angular proxy settings to enable link rerouting to have wildcard for all links that starts with */api/*
- Installed few MEAN stacks, tried to test it's potential and decided that it's way to over the limit to achieve what I want.
- Tried to combine two tools into one by starting both at same port (as you might imagine, this broke both of them).

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MongoDB in your API whithout problems, and also it's not that hard to use it, its really more simple thant DataBases that have relational objects, like SQL, PostGRES and so on. I  would recommend Hapi instead Express, but Express have a lot of information on the web, so if you are not confortable with re-search in documentation, Express would be you better option.

When i started developing in node.js it take me time to figure out that tutorials and videos only give me headache, old videos that doesent use the same Frameworks as i do, or not in the same version. So i started to take deep into the documentation, i used to pass more time reading than writing code, and it help me a lot.

The most common/simple is MEAN API, find something you like and stick with it  ^-^

Comment: And also to connect Angular4 to Node API you can use xmlhttprequest, hope this helps you.

Comment: Very interesting and informal answer, thank you I will definitely read more about Hapi. Mongo DB is not the problem tho, the problem is integration of Frontend to Backend using those two technologies